# How to add a default value to an association (foreign key) in a rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a coverage plan which I want to add to a client.  A new client should default to a provicial coverage plan, which has key 1.

Using Rails 5.0, I'm aware how to add a default value to a regular column, but how do I add a default value to a one-to-one association?  Do I need to specify the object or just the value of the key?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, it's better not to hardcode foreign_key value in migrations.

You can do something like this instead of setting a default value in migrations:

```
before_create :set_default_plan

def set_default_plan
  plan = Plan.find_by(name: 'default plan name')
  self.plan = plan if plan.present?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

your default for future data should be set in the model as @Ravi Teja Dandu suggests

however as you add the reference you can use a migration like this to let you set a non-null reference with a foreign key by using a three step process

1. set reference with foreign key, but allow null
2. manually set a value for each item
3. change the reference to disallow null

```
class AddCategoryToMenuItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

   def change
        add_reference :menu_items, :drink_category, foreign_key: true, index: true, null: true

        reversible do |change|
            change.up do
                first_category = DrinkCategory.first
                MenuItem.find_each do |item|
                    item.drink_category = first_category
                    item.save
                end

            end
        end

        change_column_null :menu_items, :drink_category_id, false
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

After running `rails generate`

```
rails g migration AddCoverageToClients coverage:reference
```

and creating the data in the child `coverages` table, specify the value of the foreign key as the default.

```
class AddCoverageToClients < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :clients, :coverage, foreign_key: true, null: false, default: 1
  end 
end
```

Comment: Note: I've traveled this route and it's quite brittle. As you said you need to have the initial row with an id of 1 in the coverage table.